# ACCESS sql code to multiply record with calculated value from previous cell

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access Database to get a value. I am fairly new to access as I usually use SQLServer and I am having trouble in getting what I want.

I have the following table, with column TARGET and incremental Target as the target column that I need to get:

```
Category|Period|Value|   TARGET       |      
A       |  4   |  1  |  1/1 =1        |          
A       |  3   |  3  |  1/(3*1)=0.33  |       (1/value at period 3 * previous target)    
A       |  2   |  6  |1/(0.33*6)=0.505|              
A       |  1   |  9  |1/(0.505*9)=0.22|
```

The data is partitioned by Category and ordered in descending order by Period.

For the first row the Target should be: (1/value at current period)
For the next rows the Target should be: (1/value at current period * value of previous target)

As you can see this is somehow complex as I need to evaluate a cell value and then for the next row I need to use the value in the cell above.

Plus I need to get the incremental value for this column as well.

Any help will be very much appreciated as I am new to Access and need to get this done soon!

Comment: When you say *previous target* do you mean the value of a period with **same category and next period?** When I say *next period* it's because I noticed your data is 4,3,2 and 1 Period. So is the previous row, but in numerical order would be the next one (so for second row, that means period 3, you use the value of previous target, that means period 4, and 4 is next integer after 3 in numerical sorting)

Comment: Do this with DAO. Open the table as a recordset and step through the records while you calculate the Target value.

Comment: Easy in Excel, not in Access. As Gustav suggests, probably need VBA.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'Plus I need to get the incremental value for this column as well.'. If this is something other than already showing in sample table, edit question to provide example.

Comment: And also, as far as i know , `Value` is a reserved word from Access, so I strongly suggest you to use a different name for that field, something like `_Value_` could easily work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function placed in general module that can be called from query. `Value` is a reserved word so I used `Data` for that field name.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Global dblTar As Double
Global strCat As String
____________

Function CalcTarget(strC As String, dblT As Double) As Double
If strCat <> strC Then
    strCat = strC
    dblTar = dblT
End If
dblTar = 1 / (dblT * dblTar)
CalcTarget = dblTar
End Function
```

Calling function in query:
`SELECT Category, Period, Data, CalcTarget([Category],[Data]) AS Target FROM Table1;`

Normally I advise not to save calculated data to table when a query can work, but if you prefer to save, then options are:

An UPDATE action: `UPDATE Table1 SET Target = CalcTarget([Category],[Data]);`

Or VBA:

```
Sub CalcTarget()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strCat As String
Dim dblTar As Double
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Category, Period DESC")
strCat = rs!Category
dblTar = rs!Data
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If rs!Category = strCat Then
        dblTar = 1 / (rs!Data * dblTar)
        rs.Edit
        rs!Target = dblTar
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Else
        strCat = rs!Category
        dblTar = rs!Data
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this code, now I want to use it in the query to add the new column TARGET. I am not sure how that is done. I tried changing CalcTarget() into a function and then writing 'SELECT columns, CalcTarget() AS TARGET' but when running this code I am getting a prompt to enter a value for CalcTarget. And this entered value is being input into the TARGET column.

Comment: Can't use this in query. Running the procedure updates TARGET field in table.  As I said in answer, don't see a way to do this calc with function called in query.

Comment: Okay, finally figured out a function. See edited answer.